# Name Suggestions for SE Blog

Tags: discussion, blog, poll

This is to discuss **name suggestions** for the blog.

1. Upvote items you like.
2. Downvote items you do not like.
3. Add new ideas as separate answers
4. Feel free to discuss titles in the comments (plus other issues, subtitles maybe?)

I think we should go for a title which is specific enough to stand out as "mathematical" (and distinct from related SE's like stats and MO) but general enough to appeal to a majority of members (i.e., not something like "the prime number press").

Comment: Exactly - I don't know!

Comment: Downvoting isn't really a problem here--if someone really hates a name idea, that should be taken into account, I think.  (But only in extreme circumstances)  EDIT: Just looked at the vote counts... this is ridiculous.

Comment: "A Much Needed Gap" is already in use.

Comment: $\displaystyle { \sqrt[{\Large\rm b}]{e^{\large \rm b{\rm log}(\rm math)}}} = $ math simplified $\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: Is the root the title, or he whole expression including the equality sign?

Comment: That is the only silly title I would actually like, @BillDubuque

Comment: Consider "Hail Awal Garg!" Everyone would like it... lol. Ok with all seriousness "Mathlog" is what I suggest...

Comment: @NikolajK Look closely, it's a valid equality for positive, real math. The idea was to find a formula that includes "blog" and "math" and hints that the blog contains expositions (simplifications) of math. So I rewrote $\rm\, blog\to  b\,log\,$ and applied it to math, and looked for simplifications.

Comment: @BillDubuque Post that as an answer!

Comment: @BillDubuque: I realized that right away, but the question remains.

Comment: We should give the blog a basic name, that everybody can understand, not name it after some theorem, proof, lemma, mathematician, etc. They are just part of mathematics not mathematics itself and the name should also reflect that. I posted some suggestions. I am thinking of more.... or should I stop ? I want the name to reflect the very essence of mathematics. What is it that we are trying to do ? What is mathematics all about ?Come on people, I know we are better than this. Yeah, yeah I don't want to get in some philosophical discussion, but something along the lines I just mentioned.

Comment: A good subtitle would be "Let no one ignorant of Mathematics leave here". Well, I am trying the best I can :-(

Comment: How about " Hakuna Matata ".

Comment: Now come to think of it, I don't like any of my suggestions. Ich weiß nicht und ich werde auch nicht wissen.

Answer (score 24):

Suggestion for "default:"

**Mathematics Community Blog**

(See http://security.blogoverflow.com/ for an example of this...)

Comment: To put this in perspective: I just looked at all the 20 other stackexchange blogs.  18 of them are called "[name of site] community blog".  The other 2 are called "[name of site] blog".

Comment: @Goos has a point--we might want to keep with the SE "brand" of blogs; that is, our blog name reflects our site name.  I think a creative subtitle could be a nice touch, but we want the branding to be strongly resemblant of the main site--after all, the core of Math.SE is the Q&A model.

Comment: Oh, I missed one. Serverfault is called "serverfault: The Stack Exchange Sysadmin Blog".

Comment: As I mentioned in the chat room, I was under the impression that there was no default naming procedure. As there appears to be one, perhaps I should remove this question? Or we could just be awesome and use a cool name...

Comment: @NotNotLogical I certainly think this question should exist, as we should have a record if someone asks "how did we decide the name for the blog?"  As to a default naming procedure: I don't think this is a "required" naming procedure, or if it signifies that everyone on the SE system is not creative and didn't want to go to the work to come up with a name.

Comment: Probably, @GraceNote or some other SE person could shed some light on whether the blog names are "set in stone" or not.  (To Grace: I'm pinging you because you seem to have given some input in the blog chatroom when we were first getting started... and you're the only SE person that I know of off the top of my head.) :)

Comment: Trying to come up with a suitable subtitle involving blogoSPHERE, but drawing a blank. May be not worth it :-/ *Math community - adding acute angles to the blogosphere*. Nope.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen A fine blogosphere?

Comment: Boooooooooooring!

Comment: Come on, guys!  How are people going to know that mathematicians are smarter than everyone else if we can't come up with an amazingly punny title?

Comment: @SpamIAm Its not true, so people are not going to know! As simple as that... But, I also don't like this title..

Comment: Naming the blog, is like naming our child. Turning out to be quite a difficult task. I don't want our child to have a boring name.

Comment: @Goos. The Server Fault blog *isn't* a community blog: that's why it has a different title. (Nor is the SO/SE blog (this is one blog, though it exists on two URLs.) However, the Christianity blog does have a clever name: Eschewmenical. (For whatever reason, it appears only in the page title, not at the top of the page. Since it's inactive, that's unlikely to be fixed.)

Answer (score 22):

**A Sufficiently Wide Margin**

In reference to Fermat's famous quote.  It also makes sense because, whereas Fermat didn't have enough room to write, in this blog people would have the space to write detailed, thoughtful expository posts.

Comment: Will you think anyone coming to the blog will recognize that reference?

Comment: @Sawarnik Uh, if they're reading a *math blog*, yes I would hope so.  Can you think of a more famous math quote?

Comment: I don't know, it makes it look like as if Fermat is the only big deal around.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe we could just write **Mathematics Commmunity Blog** and then a quote under it like "*The essence of mathematics lies in its freedom*" (Cantor said it I believe) or any other quote. Although I don't like this suggestion myself, I am sympathetic towards it.

Comment: I am upvoting this because I like the idea of 8*Mathematics Community Blog** with a subheading (as discussed in the comments to another answer), *not* because I think the subheading should be a quote (or, indeed, the specific quote you suggest).

Answer (score -1):

***Ergo***

I think this would be a neat title, given the central nature of proof in mathematics. Possible alternatives would be "therefore", "hence", etc. or a play on the famous "QED".

Comment: This fails the "Is it unique enough to find by search?" test which is relevant for naming anything on the Internet.

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's a good point.

Answer (score -1):

**An Attempt** or **Mathematics, an Attempt**
Why ? Well, isn't it what we are all trying to do, attempting to understanding what this thing called mathematics is all about.

Comment: Hmm, don't like this one too... -1

Answer (score -1):

**That which is learnt**
The word mathematics comes from the Greek μάθημα (máthēma), which, in the ancient Greek language, means "that which is learnt". (Source: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics), look under Etymology)

Answer (score -1):

**What remains to be demonstrated** (or maybe the latin translation)
Why ? As opposed to *quod erat demonstrandum*.

Answer (score -2):

**The Natural Blog**

A possible variant would be "The Natural (B)Log" or something of that nature.

Comment: I like "The Natural (B)Log"!

Answer (score -2):

**$N$ is a number**
Stole that one from [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0125425/).

Answer (score -2):

**Let us consider** or how about **Found, but not proven**
I think the quality is decreasing as I continue on with my suggestions.

Comment: Also , not that good.

Answer (score -2):

In the same vein as Bill Dubuque's answer:
$$
b\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(\text{math} - 1)^n}{n} = \text{blog(math)}
$$
or
$$
b\int_1^\text{math} \frac{dx}{x} = \text{blog(math)}
$$

Comment: You know what my problem with this is, it seems more like a good comment and a good suggestion(just that). But will it stay ? It gets hard to look at after a while. After getting assumed by it, it just becomes dry.

Answer (score -2):

**From Here to Infinity: The Mathematics Community Blog**

Answer (score -3):

**The Tangent Space: A Blog For Mathematical Digressions**

Answer (score -3):

**The Peano Bar**, featuring all-you-can-eat Fibonachos!

Comment: I like the Fibonachos :)

Comment: I like the Peano Bar!

Answer (score -3):

**A fine blogosphere**

Affine (blogo)sphere, [gettit](http://www.ams.org/notices/201203/rtx120300420p.pdf)? (Inspired by [Jyrki Lahtonen's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13608/name-suggestions-for-se-blog/13614#comment53633_13614) idea.)

Answer (score -3):

**Mathematics, a History of Counting**
Why ? This [article](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/Rote.shtml) explains the reason quite well.

Comment: I down vote this myself -1.

Answer (score -4):

**Monotonous Digressions**

Perhaps a bit morbid for a blog title, but it does bring to mind a few textbooks of mine... mathematical writing isn't typically... shall we say... *riveting*.

Comment: But don't we want the people using the blog to be riveted? :-P

Answer (score -4):

**Compact with open end**

suggesting that the individual blog entries will be the former, the blog itself the latter ...

Answer (score -4):

A couple equational possibilities (with *real* math)

$\displaystyle\qquad\ \  {\bf \sqrt[{\Large\rm b}]{e^{\large \rm b{\rm log}(\rm math)}}} = $ math simplified

$\quad \displaystyle\rm {\bf m}\sqrt[{\Large\rm b}]{{\bf se}^{\large b}\! {\bf e}^{\large \rm {\rm blog}(\rm math)}} = {\bf mse}$ math simplified

Comment: The second one is a bit confusing... I like the first one though.

Comment: What is the $b$ in $\sqrt[b]{e^\text{blog(math)}}$? doesn't it stand for Bill?

Comment: @achillehui No. The goal is to make the expression simplify to "math
" or "mse math". Therefore we need to take a $\rm b$'th root, since the radicand is $\rm \,e^{b\log(x)} = x^b\,$ for $\rm\,x = math.\,$ We want it to contain *real* math, just like the blog. See the comments to the question where I mentioned the motivation.

Comment: The first one is my favorite so far!

Comment: @achillehui It's to make "log" into "blog," since it will be a math blog.

Comment: @NotNotLogical They were not meant to be serious choices (but perhaps might inspire someone to design a better one with some math in it) [reposted since original comment omitted "not"]

Answer (score -6):

Got it!

(At least that is what I am hoping to hear from my students)

Answer (score -7):

**Green, Conservative, and Liberally Industrious**

This one is a bit silly I admit :) I think it's probably a bit too obscure to merit much attention.

And note that it is politically *neutral*, in case anyone was about to get offended.

Comment: It's a reference to Green's Theorem and Conservative vector fields. :) As I said, it's probably way too obscure. "Liberally industrious", I admit, has very little to do with math...

Answer (score -8):

**A Theorem, a Proof, and a Professor**

Ok yes, I got the idea from "The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe". I like the ring to it, and it has a nice "feel". Nostalgia from college classes...